# $.getJSON with Twitter rate_limit_api

Tags: twitter, getjson

I'm having trouble getting Twitter's rate_limit_status https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/account/rate_limit_status to work correctly.  I've used to curl and a web browser https://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json to test it and it does returns a JSON object, but when I run the code below all I get is a 200 so I know I got the response successfully.  It's not rated limited so even if I was over my limit it would still work.  I've googled it and searched this forum but I can't seem to find why my specific code isn't working.  As you can see I've put an alerts in the .getJSON function but neither goes off.  I'm using the other Twitter APIs get Friends, get Followers successfully using basically the same code as below.  I'm new to JQuery so I'm wondering if I'm missing something.  Thanks in advance for any help!

```
function getRateLimit (){
var uri = "https://api.twitter.com/1/account/rate_limit_status.json";
$.getJSON(uri, function(data) {
            alert("Alert before.");
    console.log(data["reset_time"]);
            console.log(data["remaining_hits"]);
            alert("For testing purposes.");
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents that from working. Even if it would work, it would show the rate limit for each user and not for your application. (the rate limit status for the requester's IP address is returned)

You have to to get this data on server-side, everything else makes no sense.